# Trouble Rendering Text within React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a ViewContainer in React that just serves as a general background, and then want to place a Text component inside of it. However, the text does not appear this way. But, when I place the text inside the creation of the ViewContainer, it does appear. I'd like ViewComponent to be generalizable and don't want it tied to a specific piece of text.

ViewContainer.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

export default class ViewContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return <View style = {styles.ViewContainer}><Text> Hello, this is Feed! </Text></View>
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ViewContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: 'mistyrose'
  }
});
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';

import ViewContainer from './app/components/ViewContainer'

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <ViewContainer><Text>Hello, this is my new app!</Text> </ViewContainer>
  }
}
```

The above does not render text. But if I place the text component inside the View inside ViewContainer, it works, but I don't want to do this. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Render its children: `<View style={styles.ViewContainer}>{this.props.children}</View>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to know is about `children`.

When you place an component inside another component, like you are doing in `App`. The component will be in `this.props.children`.

```
<ViewContainer>
    {// inside ViewContainer component, whatever is inside here will be in this.props.children}
    <Text>Hello, this is my new app!</Text> 
</ViewContainer>
```

So to render what is inside `ViewContainer` you need to render `this.props.children`.

```
export default class ViewContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    // this will render anything that is inside ViewContainer
    return <View style = {styles.ViewContainer}>{this.props.children}</View>
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked great! Thank you for your help.